# Converting byte[] or String to Dom Document

Tags: java, dom, arrays

How can i convert a byte[] or a String which holds my XML, to a DOM Document?

I need this in order to perform XPath on the Documnet.

Comment: I am well aware of DOM and XPath, but my question was not regarding the parsers, but the conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [DocumentBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html) and to call `parse()` on it using an [InputSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html) configured with the string of XML via a [StringReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html).

Don't call `parse()` directly with the string, since it'll interpret that string as a URI referencing the XML!